# Trouble copying and reversing parts of array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to copy a section of an input 2d array "img" and mirroring that section and copying it into the 2d array "out"

The following code does what I need

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(pad, pad))
a[:,:]=img[0:pad,0:pad]
out[0:pad,0:pad]=a[::-1,::-1]
```

But simply doing the following does not

```
out[0:pad,0:pad]=img[0:pad:-1,0:pad:-1]
```

and instead returns`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,0) into shape (2,2)` for `pad=2` and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img[0:pad:-1,0:pad:-1]
```

should be

```
img[pad-1::-1, pad-1::-1]
```

since you want the index to start at `pad-1` and step down to 0. See here for [the complete rules governing NumPy basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

For example,

```
import numpy as np

img = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23]])

pad = 2
out = img[pad-1::-1, pad-1::-1]

print(out)
```

yields

```
[[5 4]
 [1 0]]
```